# How do I get vim's :sh command to source my bashrc?

Tags: unix, vim, shell

Whenever I start a shell in vim using :sh, it doesn't source my ~/.bashrc file. How can I get it to do this automatically?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

See [`:help 'shell'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27shell%27).  You can set this string to include `-l` or `--login`, which will source your `.bashrc` file.  So, you might have a line like this in your `.vimrc`:

```
set shell=bash\ --login
```

Note that this will alter everything that invokes the shell, including `:!`.  This shouldn't be much of a problem, but you should be aware of it.

The value of this command can also be changed by setting the `$SHELL` environment variable.

Comment: You're my hero. I had done :help sh in the past, unfortunately that doesn't tell you much.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't source your .bashrc file, it may still source your .bash_profile file.  I usually make one of them a symlink to the other.  If your .bashrc performs some particularly odd one-time operations, you may have to edit it to only perform those operations with a login shell, but I've never had problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

~/.vimrc

```
cmap sh<CR> !bash --login<CR>
```

If you quickly enter "sh<Enter>" in command-line, you can start bash with sourcing ~/.bashrc. So dirty.

Comment: This problem has already been resolved in a clean way. No need to pollute our vimrc files with unnecessary mappings.