# How to make vim use the same environment as my login shell when running commands with "!"?

Tags: vim

I use `!ls` to execute bash command. But after i have configured something like `source ~/.usr_profile` in `~/.profile` file, vim won't source this file as well. So when i want to execute a function declared in `usr_profile` , i have to run `:!source ~/.usr_profile && my_command`. When i using this once or twice, it's ok. But when use it frequently, the my vimrc becomes messy.
Is there any better method to solve this problem.Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get vim's :sh command to source my bashrc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694599/how-do-i-get-vims-sh-command-to-source-my-bashrc)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Adding this line to your `~/.vimrc` should solve your immediate problem:

```
set shell=bash\ -l
```

When invoked with `-l` (`--login`), bash reads your `~/.profile` at startup (among other files) and thus everything sourced from there.

When invoked with `-i` (`--interactive`), bash reads your `~/.bashrc` at startup (among other files) and thus everything sourced from there.

Try `$ man bash` or `:h shell` and `:h shellcmdflag` for more info.

As for the differences between login and non-login shell I must admit my ignorance. [This answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/8991) may help, it's interesting, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Append the following two lines to your `.vimrc`.

```
set shell=/bin/bash    " use bash
set shellcmdflag="-ic" " flag passed to the shell to execute "!" and ":!" commands
```

P.S. It seems that the accepted answer may cause some problems when editing '.bash' files or execute a 'git commit', but I don't know why.