# How can I force nvim to source my .bash_profile when creating a terminal buffer?

Tags: vim, neovim

From my testing, it's clear that nvim doesn't source your .bash_profile when opening a new terminal buffer.  I would like to force this to happen every time a new terminal buffer is created.

To confirm this behavior:

1. open your .bash_profile in nvim
2. export a new variable like
   `ISSOURCED`
3. write out the file
4. open a terminal buffer
5. run `echo $ISSOURCED`

I've also checked that bash is running in interactive mode (it is) by executing `if tty -s; then echo interactive; fi`, based on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/512780)

However it is not a login shell, based on executing `shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'Not login shell'`, based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26782/86227).  This means that it would normally source `$HOME/.bashrc`.  Unfortunately I keep my bashrc in a different location and source it from my .bash_profile, so it isn't being picked up.

See my answer below for my current workaround and information about why it's less than ideal.

Comment: Does nvim source your bashrc file instead?

Comment: `.bash_profile` is only sourced by login shells, while `nvim` is likely starting a regular interactive shell instead.

Comment: @bstamour You should post an answer involving adding 'source $HOME/.bash_profile` to $HOME/.bashrc, I'll upvote it since you deserve the rep for pointing me in that direction and it will be useful advice for future readers.  However that still won't work for me because I don't have a $HOME/.bashrc, so I won't mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set shell=bash\ -l
```

When invoked with `-l` (`--login`), bash reads your `~/.profile` at startup (among other files) and thus everything sourced from there.

When invoked with `-i` (`--interactive`), bash reads your `~/.bashrc` at startup (among other files) and thus everything sourced from there.

`$ man bash` or `:h shell` and `:h shellcmdflag` for more info.

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9092644/1071756

Answer (score 0):

I set up a mapping to open a new terminal:

```
nnoremap <leader>z :new<CR>:terminal<CR>
```

To source my .bash_profile, I changed it to this:

```
nnoremap <leader>z :new<CR>:terminal<CR>source $HOME/.bash_profile<CR>c<CR>
```

The problem with this solution is that it breaks if you try to open a terminal buffer in any way other than with this mapping